# Pointer in Struct in C - How to assign the value of a given void pointer to a pointer in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I'm new to C and I'm having difficulties figuring out how to give assign the value of the given void pointer to my pointer in the struct without messing up the memory. After running a debugging program I saw that this function wasn't clearing the memory right. It was missing one free().

```
struct data_t{
   int datasize;
   void *data;
}

struct data_t *data_create2(int size, void *data) {
   if(size < 1 || data == NULL)
      return NULL;

   struct data_t *d = data_create(size); //creates a new element of data_t and reserves the necessary memory

   memcpy(d -> data, data, size);

   return d;
};
```

After this function is called, there is another function, data_destroy that destroys the structure returned, in this case *d*.

What am I doing wrong? If any more code is necessary please ask

Comment: `d->data=data;` You are assigning the beginning address to the allocated block to your pointer. Also never put spaces around `" -> "` (bad form) If `data` isn't already allocated, then you can allocate permanent storage for that and then `memcpy` We need to see how what you pass as `void *data` is declared and initialized to provide a definite answer.

Comment: The definition of `data_create` would be very helpful here

Comment: There's not enough here to see what you might be doing wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `ever put spaces around " -> " (bad form)` I do it for 30y and it is my preferred form. So David, am I a bad programmer?

Comment: This site's guidelines require that you provide a [mre] when asking code-related questions. A MRE means code that we can copy and paste into a code editor, compile and run in order to reproduce the issue. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: @0___________ - no, not a bad programmer, you can be a great programmer just using what most consider to be bad form `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a bit different way to have only one dynamic memory allocation (and consequently only one free as well)

Use proper types for sizes. In C standard defines `size_t` for this purpose

```
typedef struct 
{
   size_t datasize;
   unsigned char data[];
}mydatatype;


mydatatype *alloc(size_t size)
{
    mydatatype *md = malloc(sizeof(*md) + size);

    if(md)
    {
        md -> datasize = size;
    }
    return md;
}

mydatatype *data_create2(size_t size, void *data) 
{
    mydatatype *result = NULL;

    if(size && data)
    {
        result = alloc(size);
        if(result)
        {
            memcpy(result -> data, data, size);
        }
    }
   return result;
}

void data_destroy(mydatatype *md)
{
    free(md);
}
```

Comment: Ah, using a FAM instead of a pointer for `data` in the struct. That works fine, only limitations is you could then never have an array of `mydatatype`.A FAM is a great solution absent that case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you can have array of pointers to this strut. Still less allocations than with pointer in the struct

Comment: Array of pointers is fine, but an array of struct including a FAM or including a struct with a FAM as a member of another struct (or union) isn't allowed. [C11 Standard - 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3)

Comment: @David I do not know how it is related to my comment?